# How to create new screenshots with each new loop?

Tags: python, loops, screenshot

I'm trying to run a macro that takes a new screenshot with each run of the loop. Each time it just rewrites the new loop to the old screenshot file, so I only end up with 1 file that has been rewritten many times instead of many tiles.

I've tried using `pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'shift', '3')`, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
pyautogui.click(154, 772)
time.sleep(2)
while LoopA < 500:
    from subprocess import call
    call(["screencapture", "screenshot.jpg"])
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'w')
print("Screenshots of all files completed")
```

Expected results are to create a new file with each run of the loop instead of rewriting the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You always create a screenshot with the same name in the `call` statement. That way you always overwrite the existing one. You could always create a new file with:

```
while LoopA < 500:
    call(["screencapture", "screenshot_" + str(LooopA) + ".jpg"])
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'w')
print("Screenshots of all files completed")
```

or In Python 3.6+

```
while LoopA < 500:
    call(["screencapture", f"screenshot_{LooopA}.jpg"])
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'w')
print("Screenshots of all files completed")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like naming the screenshot according to the loop:

`call(["screencapture", "screenshot{}.jpg".format(loop_counter)]`

Where `loop_counter` is the current loop. Other possibility would be using the current system time (with datetime library, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that when you run `call(["screencapture", "screenshot.jpg"])`, you're taking a screenshot and saving it to "screenshot.jpg", hence overwriting it in each loop.

You'd need to change the name of the output file in each loop (e.g., by keeping a counter, or doing it as part of a for loop):

```
counter = 0
while LoopA < 500:
    counter += 1
    call(["screencapture", "screenshot_{}.jpg".format(counter)])
    time.sleep(2)
```